# Parse XML file from url using php

Tags: php, xml, file, parsing

I want to parse xml file from another server.

```
<?php

    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://example_page.com/api/test.xml');

?>
```

And this code work only if this file is on this same server as page, but I have got xml file on another server.

Warning from webpage:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://example_page.ugu.pl/api/test.xml) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: Connection refused in /virtual/z/y/example_page.ugu.pl/index.php on line 14

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://example_page.com/api/test.xml" in /virtual/z/y/example_page.ugu.ugu.pl/index.php on line 14
```

P.S. allow_url_fopen is still on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like there is some redirection problem in the url you are accessing, and most probably `simplexml_load_file()` doesn't follow redirects...

So the solution would be to use `file_get_contents()` or `cUrl`...

As `file_get_contents()` is easier, I am showing that only...

The code would have to be something like:

```
<?php

    $xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://example_page.ugu.pl/api/test.xml'));

?>
```

More:

```
<?php

    $xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://jakdojade.pl/pages/api/outputs/schedules.xml'));

?>
```

^ That too, totally works!

Comment: Using this I have got still error. Warning: file_get_contents(http://example_page.com/api/test.xml) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection refused in /virtual/z/y/examle_page.com/index.php on line 24 P.S. I'm sure that allow_url_fopen is on, coz I checked it using phpinfo();

Comment: The reason is nothing, but the web page you are trying to access is... down... And... really tbh, did you try to access http://example_page.com/api/test.xml from your browser?

Comment: And so, does the code works... I tried the link you provided and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: Is there any option that http://www.hostinger.com don't support it or block it? Am I using bad hosting? Which one free hosting support it?

Comment: To recommend one, I would probably suggest you AWS... there is a free plan there....

Comment: Very simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use CURL (if is active).

```
$url = "http://www.you-web-here.com/";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xmlString = curl_exec($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP Documentation:

```
Note:
Libxml 2 unescapes the URI, so if you want to pass e.g. b&c as the URI parameter a, you have to call simplexml_load_file(rawurlencode('http://example.com/?a=' . urlencode('b&c'))). Since PHP 5.1.0 you don't need to do this because PHP will do it for you.
```

So. which version are you used?

Or, you can try like this:

```
$xml_content = file_get_content('http://example_page.com/api/test.xml');
xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_content);
```

Comment: Ah,sorry, is file_get_contents, not file_get_content, lost a s chart