# PHP writing file contents from url to a local file

Tags: php

I am presently attempting to take an xml file from a website and place it in a local empty xml file (`myxml.xml`). My code as is returns an empty file.

The goal is to take the xml file content from `http://website.com/theirxml.xml` and place it in `myxml.xml`.

To note, the only reason I am doing this is because the xml on my host's website is incorrectly formatted, so I need to change it on my own local version. Thus, what I need is to acquire the strings from the file.

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("myxml.xml", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://website.com/theirxml.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
fwrite($myfile, $output);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: I get no response and no error statement.

Comment: Whether your way or @colbuton's way (which I prefer) use `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Also helps to do a little bit of searching first too. Just googling your question gives 3 SO articles all on this subject. Probably the best one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37044817/parse-xml-file-from-url-using-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simple:

```
file_put_contents('myxml.xml', file_get_contents('http://website.com/theirxml.xml');
```

Thx to JasonChen for this tip: You need to have `allow_url_fopen` in your php.ini activated.

Comment: The only issue with your way is that I get a `connection refused` error.

Comment: @JasonChen have you checked your phpinfo to make sure `allow_url_fopen` is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

you can get the data from the XML by using "simplexml_load_file" Function.

```
$url="http://website.com/theirxml.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
file_put_contents('myxml.xml',$xml);
```